# Problem setting a flag inside a TikZ `\foreach` loop

Tags: tikz-pgf, loops, foreach

I'm pulling my hair out trying to understand why the following doesn't work. The intention is to calculate whether a given number `#1` is prime, and to set `\isprime` to either `1` (true) or `0` (false). The looping and the conditionals are doing the right thing, but the `\isprime` flag isn't being set properly.

```
 \newcommand{\setisprime}[1]{
   \def\isprime{1}
   \foreach \i in {2, 3,5,...,#1} {
     \pgfmathparse{\i*\i>#1? 1:0}
     \ifthenelse{\pgfmathresult=1}{
       % Early-out if \i^2 > #1
       \breakforeach
     }{
       % Otherwise test if \i divides #1
       \pgfmathparse{Mod(#1,\i)==0? 1:0}
       \ifthenelse{\pgfmathresult=1}{
         \def\isprime{0}
         \breakforeach
       }{}
     }
   }
 }
```

Here's what happens:

[image: example]

Obviously, it's failing quite badly!

Here's an MWE with debugging statements:

```
 \documentclass{article}
 \pagestyle{empty}

 \usepackage{tikz}
 \usepackage{ifthen}

 \begin{document}

 \newcommand{\debugsetisprime}[1]{
   Testing #1 for primeness.\par
   \def\isprime{1}
   \foreach \i in {2, 3,5,...,#1} {
     \pgfmathparse{\i*\i>#1? 1:0}
     \ifthenelse{\pgfmathresult=1}{
       Exiting loop because $\i^2 > #1$.\par
       \breakforeach
     }{
       Testing whether \i\ divides #1...
       \pgfmathparse{Mod(#1,\i)==0? 1:0}
       \ifthenelse{\pgfmathresult=1}{
         Yes.\par Exiting loop because divisor found.\par
         \def\isprime{0}
         \breakforeach
       }{
         No.\par
       }
     }
   }
   \ifnum\isprime=1
     #1 is prime.\par\vskip1em
   \else
     #1 is not prime.\par\vskip1em
   \fi
 }

 \debugsetisprime{97}
 \debugsetisprime{15}

 \end{document}
```

Comment: `\foreach` loops are computed in a group; use `\gdef` instead of `\def`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem here is that the redefinition of `\isprime` to `0` in

```
\def\isprime{0}
```

is made inside a group. As such, it is local and doesn't "survive" outside the group. Use

```
\global\def\isprime{0}
```

instead (or `\gdef` for short). There is no need for this `\global` definition when initializing `\isprime`, since it is at the same depth as the eventual test for primeness.

Comment: Sweet!!! Huh, all this time I never knew that defintions in TeX weren't all global. This is great news!